# Cross validation with unequal sample size for the left out sets

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, sample-size, likelihood, cluster-sample

I am trying to do cross validation on several (20) subsets of samples, which all have unequal sample size. I cannot subsample so that sizes are equal. Example:

batch 1: 500 samples
batch 2: 400 samples
batch 3: 250 samples
...

When I compute the likelihood on all but one of these batches, training and testing accuracy will be affected by training and testing sample sizes. I suspect just taking an average of the testing likelihoods will not do. A weighted average may be closer to right, but how to chose the weights? I could weight by test sample size, but that does not take into account the fact that when I have a smaller test set, I train on a larger train set, which makes the learned model more accurate.

Any suggestions/references?

Comment: If I were always training with the same sample, I would understand how taking a weighted average of the log-likelihood would be OK (this is equivalent to just training on the whole test set without partitioning it). However, I am not sure this would account for the fact that the training set has a different size each time I change my test set. Or would you think this is not the case? Also, I am not sure what you mean by computing the variance of deviance for each block.